# GET Master volume in Windows XP/Vista/Seven (the one increased through keyboard wheel normally)

Tags: c#, windows, audio

I know a lot of people asked this but I didn't read any answer, are there any lib/a generic way to GET (not set, I don't need it) the master volume (the volume of the current source of output for sounds, not voice) which works for both xp/vista/seven ?

If not, how to do it for xp, vista, seven (I'll write my generic wrapper)

I need to show a bar (progress bar) to show how is set the current volume (winform control)

**Edit:**

I found a useful link, I'm testing it but I won't check the answer 'till I get something that works 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/mixerSetControlDetails.aspx?display=Print

**Edit 2:**

An important thing: the previous way to analyze volume won't work on windows vista or later, use this lib instead:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx

I don't know if really works well because I don't have vista/seven at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [mixerGetNumDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the related API help? (You have to go through all the devices with `mixerGetLineControls`, etc. and see which `MIXERCONTROL` says "Volume" for the name; there's also a way to check the flag. That's the one you're looking for.)

---

Edit:

Here's a snippet of some old code I had; I don't think it compiles, and it's not great code (I just needed to get stuff done), but it should be helpful:

```
MMRESULT mmResult = mixerOpen(&hMixer, 0, (DWORD_PTR)hWnd, NULL, CALLBACK_WINDOW | MIXER_OBJECTF_MIXER);
if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR == mmResult)
{
    MIXERLINE mxl;
    mxl.cbStruct = sizeof(MIXERLINE);
    mxl.dwComponentType = MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_DST_SPEAKERS;
    MMRESULT mmResult = mixerGetLineInfo((HMIXEROBJ)hMixer, &mxl, MIXER_OBJECTF_HMIXER | MIXER_GETLINEINFOF_COMPONENTTYPE);
    if (mmResult == MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
    {
        MIXERLINECONTROLS controls;
        memzero(&controls, sizeof(controls));
        controls.cbStruct = sizeof(controls);
        controls.cControls = 1;
        controls.dwLineID = mxl.dwLineID;
        controls.cbmxctrl = sizeof(MIXERCONTROL); //one element only!!
        MIXERCONTROL controlsArray[2]; //First element: volume, second element: mixer
        memzero(&controlsArray, sizeof(controlsArray));
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(controlsArray) / sizeof(*controlsArray); i++) { controlsArray[0].cbStruct = sizeof(controlsArray[0]); }

        controls.dwControlType = MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_VOLUME;
        controls.pamxctrl = &controlsArray[0]; //NOTE: this is ZERO
        mmResult = mixerGetLineControls((HMIXEROBJ)hMixer, &controls, MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYTYPE | MIXER_OBJECTF_HMIXER);
        if (mmResult == MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        {
            controls.dwControlType = MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_MUTE;
            controls.pamxctrl = &controlsArray[1]; //NOTE: this is ONE
            mmResult = mixerGetLineControls((HMIXEROBJ)hMixer, &controls, MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYTYPE | MIXER_OBJECTF_HMIXER);
            if (mmResult == MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                bool isVolume = controls[0].dwControlID == (DWORD)lParam;
                bool isMute = controls[1].dwControlID == (DWORD)lParam;
                if (isVolume | isMute)
                {
                    MIXERCONTROLDETAILS details;
                    memzero(&details, sizeof(details));
                    details.cbStruct = sizeof(details);
                    details.cChannels = 1;
                    details.dwControlID = (DWORD)lParam;
                    MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED controlDetail;
                    memzero(&controlDetail, sizeof(controlDetail));
                    details.paDetails = &controlDetail;
                    details.cbDetails = sizeof(controlDetail);
                    MMRESULT mmResult = mixerGetControlDetails((HMIXEROBJ)hMixer, &details, MIXER_GETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE | MIXER_OBJECTF_HMIXER);
                    if (mmResult == MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it works (well, I'm newbie to this argument), does it works on vista/seven too?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I don't see why it wouldn't... it's not deprecated or anything.

Comment: Should I use waveOutGetVolume to get the volume of a waveoutput device?

Comment: I'm reading it, I love you by the way for the big code example! I need the "stuff done" as you, I would like only to read the master volume to show it... I hoped it would be easier