# C# Get System Audio Volume via Windows API

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, dllimport

I've been trying to get the current system volume using C# / Windows API. I'm on Windows 8.1 though I would like the solution to also work on Windows 7.

This:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);
```

does not work, with the system volume after Windows XP.

I have tried this:

```
    [DllImport("Audioses.dll", EntryPoint = "GetMasterVolume", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetMasterVolume(out float pfLevelDB);

    public void getVolume()
    {
        float f = 0.0F;
        int i = GetMasterVolume(out f);

        MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());
    }
```

However the application never gets to the MessageBox.Show(...), though running line-by-line shows that it gets to GetMasterVolume(out f) then fails. I think something must be wrong with my declaration or usage.

Output shows:    System.EntryPointNotFoundException

GetMasterVolumeLevel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316533(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629816/get-master-volume-in-windows-xp-vista-seven-the-one-increased-through-keyboard

Comment: `DllImport` does not apply to `GetMasterVolume`, you just need a proper use of this API...

Answer (score 0):

`EntryPointNotFound` indicates that the declaration is indeed mistaken, and your implementation cannot find the method you're requesting within the specified dll. The biggest I see here is that the `ISimpleAudioVolume` is an interface, and thus the desired method is an instance, not a static, method, and requires more work to grab an instance of the appropriate type and return the desired volume levels. Note that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531(v=vs.85).aspx) and on the interface itself mentions needing to start an audio session to operate through this interface.